# Why is it not possible to use a template alias in function as parameter and to be automatically deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias, template-aliases

I was trying to simplify a template function by using a template alias instead of the underlying type:

```
template<typename T,
    typename Traits = std::char_traits<T>,
    typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>,
    typename String = std::basic_string<T, Traits, Allocator>,
    typename Vector = std::vector<String>>
Vector make_vector_from_string(const String & str)
{
    //do something with str parameter

    return Vector{
        {str}
    };
}
```

But the caller is required to specify the template type because the compiler fails to deduce T for the parameter:

```
std::string bar{"bar"};
auto strings{make_vector_from_string<char>(bar)};
```

If the function parameter type is changed to `std::basic_string<T, Traits, Allocator>` instead of `String` the caller can simply call `make_vector_from_string(bar);` without having to specify the template parameter. Why is that?

Comment: Just do `template<typename String>
std::vector<String> make_vector_from_string(const String & str)`;

Comment: `T` is non deducible, only `String` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is non deducible, only `String` is.

If you want to provide type automatically for `T`, `Traits`, `Allocator`. You have to do it the other way:

```
template <
    typename String,
    typename T = typename String::value_type,
    typename Traits = typename String::traits_type,
    typename Allocator = typename String::allocator_type,
    typename Vector = std::vector<String>>
Vector make_vector_from_string(const String& str)
{
    //do something with str parameter

    return {str};
}
```

But

```
template <typename String>
std::vector<String> make_vector_from_string(const String& str)
{
    //do something with str parameter

    return {str};
}
```

Seems enough.

Or even

```
std::vector<std::string> make_vector_from_string(const std::string& str)
{
    return { str};
}
```